# Replace every caret with a superscript in a python string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace every caret character with a unicode superscript, for nicer printing of equations in python. My problem is, every caret may be followed by a different exponent value, so in the unicode string u'\u00b*', the * wildcard needs to be the exponent I want to print in the string. I figured some regex would work for this, but my experience with that is very little.

For example, supposed I have a string
    "x^3-x^2"
, I would then want this to be converted to the unicode string 
    u"x\u00b3-x\u00b2"

Comment: @Chris just unicode text

Comment: You should show us your attempt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` and `str.translate` to catch exponents and change them to unicode superscripts.

```
import re

def to_superscript(num):
    transl = str.maketrans('1234567890', '¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰')
    return num.translate(transl)

s = 'x^3-x^2'

out = re.sub('\^\s*(\d+)', lambda m: to_superscript(m[1]), s)

print(out)
```

### Output

```
x³-x²
```